# How to split emails by no space , comma , semi-colon, and space using Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split emails by no space, comma, semi-colon, and space using Regex. I have this string:

```
var emails = "user1@email.comuser2gmail.com user3@email.com;user4@gmail.com, user5@email.com"
```

and I'm trying to get all emails in putll them in an array using this Regex:

```
function extractEmails() {
 return emails.match(/\w+@\w+.com/); 
}
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas on how get all emails using Regex? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't see a way to split something like `user1@email.comuser2gmail.com` unless you maintain a list of TLDs, which the last time I checked was [pretty long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains)

Comment: *"by no space"* - You can't. What if the top-level domain in the address started with the same letters as some other top-level domain? E.g., should "bargainshunter" be split to "bar" and "gainshunter", or to "bargains" and "hunter"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add the `g` modifier, to get all matches:

```js
var emails = "user1@email.comuser2gmail.com\nuser3@email.com;user4@gmail.com, user5@email.com";

function extractEmails() {
 return emails.match(/\w+@\w+.com/g); 
}

console.log(
  extractEmails(emails)
);
```

(This will only work as long as none of the part before the @ contains `.com`, of course, and should there be a `barcom.com` domain it would fail as well ...)

Comment: Hi CBroe, Thank you for your input. Is there any way to throw an error if there are 2 emails separated by NO SPACE?

Comment: Well if you only need to match addresses ending in `.com`, then this should work as-is (apart from the mentioned edge cases.) As for checking whether you got a `foo@bar.comlorem@ipsum` in the results, I would recommend to loop over them and test each individually using a second regex that tests for this kind of pattern; cramming both into one might get rather complex.

Comment: If you need to match any TLD (.app, .io, .network, .org etc), I found this works well for me: `emails.match(/\w+@\w+.\w+/g);`